# Creating an object with a nested form - how to pass params to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm really struggling with how to make a form create an object, and two sub-objects. My Guide has_one City_obj and has_one Country_obj.

guide.rb

```
class Guide < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :city_obj, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :country_obj, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :guide_pics, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :city_obj, :country_obj
end
```

city_obj.rb

```
class CityObj < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :guide
  belongs_to :country_obj
end
```

country_obj.rb

```
class CountryObj < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :guides
  has_many :city_obj, dependent: :destroy
end
```

new.html

```
<%= form_for(@guide) do |f| %>

  <%= render 'new_form_part', f: f, field: 'name', label: 'name', type: 'text_field', 

  <%= f.fields_for :country_obj, @guide.country_obj do |p| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :city_obj, @guide.city_obj do |p| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In my controller create method, I get

```
params[:guide] = {"name"="whatever is submitted for city"}
```

That's because the partial that sets :name is being overwritten by the text_fields below. How can I get them to pass params[:guide][:city_obj][:name] and params[:guide][:country_obj][:name]?

UPDATE: There is a typo. I should be using p.text_field, not f.text_field

Comment: After typing this in, I noticed the typo in the text_field tags. They should use p.text_field.

Comment: please show whole controller code